# C# use quaternions on a 3D cube in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, quaternions

I'm using a sensor which is sending quaternions to my PC. Now I want to rotate a cube I have created on my application.

```
<Viewport3D Name="viewport3D1" Margin="568,-85,-104,176" RenderTransformOrigin="0.317,0.482">

        <Viewport3D.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Viewport3D.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>

                        <QuaternionAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myQuaternionRotation3D" />

                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Viewport3D.Triggers>
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camMain" Position="6 5 4" LookDirection="-6 -5 -4">
            </PerspectiveCamera>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <DirectionalLight x:Name="dirLightMain" Direction="-1,-1,-1">
                </DirectionalLight>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <GeometryModel3D>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="meshMain"
                            Positions="0 0 0  1 0 0  0 1 0  1 1 0  0 0 1  1 0 1  0 1 1  1 1 1"
                            TriangleIndices="2 3 1  2 1 0  7 1 3  7 5 1  6 5 7  6 4 5  6 2 0  2 0 4  2 7 3  2 6 7  0 1 5  0 5 4">
                        </MeshGeometry3D>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="matDiffuseMain">
                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                </GeometryModel3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>
```

I found some examples on the internet but they don't work. I added a QuaternionAnimation function like this.

```
                private void cube_Rotation(string[] text) { 
        try
        {
            Double WValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(text[0]);
            Double XValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(text[1]);
            Double YValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(text[2]);
            Double ZValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(text[3]);

            endQuaternion = new Quaternion(XValue, YValue, ZValue, WValue);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Set non-null values for the quaternion.");
        }

        myQuaternionRotation3D = new QuaternionRotation3D(endQuaternion);
        myRotateTransform3D.Rotation = myQuaternionRotation3D;

        //update matrix display
        qrotationMatrix3D = myRotateTransform3D.Value;
    }
```

Also, the initialization doesn't work properly. Does someone have any idea or an example using quaternions on a 3D cube in WPF? I would be glad if someone can help me.

Comment: *doesn't work* isn't a really helpful description. Can you explain what's not working? Start with the initialization. Common error with animations are issues with offsets and origin mismatch. Also, converting text to double's can be tricky. You might want to check the thread's culture info to avoid misinterpretation with decimal separator symbol `.` vs `,`.

Comment: I used this code https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.media3d.quaternion(v=vs.110).aspx and tried to change it. i created on my XAML the object "myQuaternionRotation3D" but i cant use it in my .cs file

Comment: *"but i cant use it in my .cs"*; why? Do you get a compiler error of some sort? Please provide some more information about errors and/or symptoms. As for now your question is unclear. See: [mcve] or [ask] for more info.

Comment: All compiler errors are CS0103: The name ' ' does not exist in the current context..

Comment: Usually there is an actual name between the `''`

Comment: Please note that this line: `Quaternion endQuaternion = new Quaternion(XValue, YValue, ZValue, WValue);` doesn't do anything.

Comment: The CS0103 appears on: 'endQuaternion' in the try brackets, also on 'myQuaternionRotation3D' which i initialized in the XAML code for the cube, 'myQuaternion3D' and in the same line 'endQuaternion', 'myRotateTransform3D', same line 'myQuaternionRotation3D' and the last line qrotationMatrix3D and myRotateTransform3D

Comment: There are too many thing wrong here. Non of your variables seems to be defined. First, naming variables in XAML is done by the `x:Name` attribute. Second, your scope of `endQuaternion` is wrong, you'll need to put `Quaternion endQuaternion = null;` outside of the try `{` block.